# Why do you write "receive" with "ei" but "retrieve" with "ie"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it true that “I before E, except after C”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34356/why-is-it-true-that-i-before-e-except-after-c)

Both words are similar in pronunciation but different in spelling. Why is it that *receive* is written with *ei* but *retrieve* has the diphthong the other way round?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the cited post? What is common between them? (I have analyzed both carefully.)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate per se, but they essentially have the same answer (discrepancies/inconsistencies in spelling are derived from the many differing roots of English words, especially French, Latin, and German).