# Is it true that the "i before e" rule is vastly untrue?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, exceptions

After reading questions like [Why is it true that "I before E, except after C"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34356/why-is-it-true-that-i-before-e-except-after-c), and searching for the rule on Google, I happened upon the following image:

[image: There are 923 words that break the "i before e" rule. Only 44 words actually follow that rule.]

This claims that only 44 out of the 967 English words with E and I next to each other are ordered as according to the rule "I before E except after C, or when sounding like A as in *neighbor* and *weigh*". **Is it true that ~95% of such words break the popular rule?**

Comment: *I* before *e*, **except** after *c*, or when pronounced as *a*, as in *neighbor* and *weigh*. The two exceptions are actually a part of the rule, and with **all three** principles applied, the rule is consistent--but not universal. And further [principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C) add accuracy.

Comment: It doesn't, actually. It claims the same that QI claimed, namely that there are 923 words where _i before e, except after c_ (with no further conditioning at all) is untrue, and only 23/44 (depending on the source) where it's true. If that's how you define the rule, then yes, I'm sure it's true. That's not how the rule is _actually_ defined, though, as several comments in the question you link to point out. If the rule is **correctly** defined, then there are only perhaps four or five exceptions, and presumably still 23/44 corroborations.

Comment: @Scot That's not the actual rule either, though it's a frequently heard rhyming version. The actual rule deals only with choosing between <ei> and <ie> as the spelling of stressed /i:/, nothing else. The only exceptions I can think of are (invariably) _weir(d)_ and (with variation) _(n)either, leisure, seize_ and their derivatives.

Comment: Gah! Correcting myself here: _seize_ should of course have been in the invariable category, not the variable one.

Comment: Amen, @JanusBahsJacquet! And the ubiquitous exception to every spelling rule explains why I rely so heavily on my computer's spellcheck program ;-)

Comment: I think I'm going to make up a new, more accurate rhyming version to teach school kids. How about “I before E except after C, when the vowel is stressed, with the sound of _key_”?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was taught "I before E except after C **when the sound is E**"

Comment: @AndrewLeach Which works for most Brits, but partly fails for at least some Americans who pronounce the _happy_ vowel like /i:/ (with length)—hence the stress conditioning. But yes: **I before E, except after C, when the vowel is stressed and the sound is E** sounds good to me!

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C#cie) says that this comes from the fact that a trivia show claimed there are 923 words with *cie* and only 44 with *cei* (from a Scrabble word list). This may be true: *accuracies, adjacencies, advocacies, agencies, aristocracies, ...*.

Comment: @PeterShor I think JBJ is right. Stress is important.